# WebApi application on Azure returning 500 errors for some endpoints

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api2

I am setting up an ASP.NET WebApi application running on the Azure web application environment. Most of my controllers and endpoints work fine, but there are about 10 routes that return 500 errors "An error has occured".  It's not random. It's the same routes every time and I can find no pattern (not all the HTTP methods, from different controllers where other routes in that same controller work fine, and so forth)

When these errors occur, no error logging gets triggered as far as I can tell in the app. (I am using Raygun.IO if that matters). I tried adding a global.asax file with following lines in the Application_Error function:

```
Exception ex = Server.GetLastError();
new RaygunClient().SendInBackground(null, ex);
```

but as far as I can see, it doesn't get triggered when these 500 errors occur. The only thing I have found in the Azure server logs is the following warning in the Failed Requests log:

[image]

However, I don't see any errors in the trace previous to that point. I'm also not finding any other errors in any of my Azure logs that I can relate to these failing routes.

It's .NET 4.6 (tried 4.5.1 and 4.5.2 with no difference) WebApi using an OWIN startup class. Also tried updating all my packages to no effect.

Comment: Instead of hooking the global.asax Application_Error, try hooking either the Web API 2.0 ExceptionHandler or ExceptionLogger interfaces.  Don't bother with an ExceptionFilterAttribute.  This article explains all three:
https://ruhul.wordpress.com/2014/09/05/how-to-handle-exceptions-globally-in-asp-net-webapi-2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what was going on. There were actual errors occurring (mostly SQL related), but the way that we had configured the functions and error logging in those functions, the actual errors were being swallowed up and lost, overriding the error logging behavior of Raygun. I went through and ripped out the Try/Catch blocks we were using for error trapping and logging and the real errors finally emerged into the Raygun dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

Check to be sure you don't have routes that conflict.  When a URI matches two or more controller actions, and thus Web API can't pick one, you will get a 500 error.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a consistent repro, then you can use remote debugging to attach to your web app and debug it (https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-dotnet-troubleshoot-visual-studio/). If you can repro it through the browser, you can also turn the custom errors page off so that it shows the stack trace through the browser (`<customErrors mode="off"/>` under `<server.web>`).

Also, you can enable better diagnostic logs using the web app settings. Information on how to do so is here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-configure/ under the section "Enabling diagnostic logs".

Also, as Brent said, URL conflicts can cause some nasty errors which aren't immediately obvious.